# Prove that $\log(n + 10) = Θ(\log n)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics, computational-complexity

Would $\log(n + 10) = Θ(\log n)$?

I was having trouble with this because I wasn't sure if I could get rid of the $10$ inside the log as a lower order term.

Comment: What happens with $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{log(n+10)}{log(n)}$?

Comment: It would approach 1. So essentially neither term would dominate each other, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint :

prove that $$\log n < \log(n+10) < 2\log n$$

for some $n > N$. Consider that $\log(n+10) = \log n + \log(1+\frac{10}{n})$.